# Странный шрифт в терминале VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Странный шрифт в `VSCode`, переустановка и обновление не помогли.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что проблема просто со шрифтом. Симуляция поведения вашего терминала

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Как поправить

1. Открыть `Command Palette`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Ввести `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`
3. В открывшемся JSON файле дописать, например

   ```json
    "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Consolas"
   ```
4. Смотрим изменения
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В приниципе в настройку можно написать любой `font family`, который поддерживается вашей системой и который более приятен глазу.